# Do I need to add RowVersion TimeStamp type property "Entity Framework Code First" to Parent and Child classes?

Tags: c#-4.0, concurrency, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

My question here is if I should place a RowVersion [TimeStamp] property in every
entity in my domain model.
For Example: I have an Order class and an OrderDetails "navigation, reference" property,
should I use a RowVersion property for both entities, or is it enough to the parent object?

These classes are pocos meant to be used with Entity Framework Code First approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, as often, is "it depends".

Since it will almost always be possible to have an `Order` without any `OrderDetail`s, you're right that the parent object should have a `RowVersion` property.

Is it possible to modify an `OrderDetail` *without* also modifying the `Order`? Should it be?

If it isn't possible and shouldn't be, a `RowVersion` property at the detail level doesn't add anything. You already catch all possible modifications by checking the `Order`'s `RowVersion`. In that case, only add the property at the top level, and stop reading here.

Otherwise, if two independent contexts load the same order and details, both modify a different `OrderDetail`, and both try to save, do you want to treat this as a conflict? In some cases, this makes sense. In other cases, it doesn't. To treat it as a conflict, the simplest solution is to actually mark the *`Order`* as modified too if it is unchanged (using `ObjectStateEntry.SetModified`, not `ObjectStateEntry.ChangeState`). EF will check and cause an update to the `Order`'s `RowVersion` property, and complain if anyone else made any modifications.

If you do want to allow two independent contexts to modify two different `OrderDetail`s of the same `Order`, yes, you need a `RowVersion` attribute at the detail level.

That said: if you load an `Order` and its `OrderDetail`s into the same context, modify an `OrderDetail`, and save your changes, *Entity Framework may also check and update the `Order`'s `RowVersion`*, even if you don't actually change the `Order`, causing bogus concurrency exceptions. This has been labelled a bug, and a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624) is available, or you can install .NET Framework 4.5 (currently available in release candidate form), which fixes it even if your application uses .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer hvd. These were my thoughts too. I think there should be OrderDetails modifications without changing the Order. But as I can see there wont be any context without an Order, so changing the OrderDetail(s) and send back the Order -> OrderDetails, EF should make the appropriate checks and change the RowVersion :)

Comment: @hvd: I wish I could say "you saved my day" :-) Thanks, though